# How can I output text to another console already open C++

Tags: c++, winapi, stdout, handle, access-rights

Hi this is my first question on stack overflow
(Im a junior programmer :P and french too...So apologies in advance for gramatical mistake I make)

Im trying to start a elevated process to attach back to the console of the parent to write its output

(no crash no error just plain nothingness)

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (UAC::IsAppRunningAsAdminMode())
    {
        printf("Process Already elevated\nChecking if self invocated from unprevileged previous run...\n");
         if (argc > 1)
        {
            std::string consoleTextOutputBuffer("Elevated privileges session started...\n");
             WriteConsoleA((HANDLE)argv[2], consoleTextOutputBuffer.c_str(), consoleTextOutputBuffer.size(), NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Process need elevation...\n");
        if (UAC::BeginPrivilegeElevationPrompt(consoleHandle))
        {
            printf("Elevation succesfull!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Elevation failed\n");
            system("pause>nul");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

And From the class UAC that I wrote:

```
BOOL BeginPrivilegeElevationPrompt(const HANDLE& oldConsoleHandle)
{
    wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath)))
    {
        // Launch itself as admin
        std::string oldConsoleHandleToString = std::to_string((int)oldConsoleHandle);
        std::wstring wsConsoleString(oldConsoleHandleToString.begin(), oldConsoleHandleToString.end());
        SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = { sizeof(sei) };
        sei.lpVerb = L"runas";
        sei.lpFile = szPath;
        sei.hwnd = NULL;
        sei.lpParameters = wsConsoleString.c_str();
        sei.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
        if (!ShellExecuteEx(&sei))
        {
            DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
            if (dwError == ERROR_CANCELLED)
            {
                // The user refused to allow privileges elevation.
                printf("User did not allow elevation.\n");
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
            _exit(1);  // Quit itself
        }
    }
    printf("Could not load module name.\n");
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Your title is a question, but I'm not sure how it relates to your code.  What is it that isn't working?

Comment: The console screen-buffer handle value is meaningless in the elevated process. Passing it as an argument is pointless.  Are you looking for the elevated process to attach back to the console of the parent to write its output? That's possible.

Comment: Where do you convert the string back to a handle? What is the result? Does it not work at all, print something incorrect, crash?

Comment: @eryksun Yes thats Exacly what im trying to do Thx for pointing that out. Im french so trying to explain myself is a bit hard

Comment: @RetiredNinja The idea was to convert the Handle to a string, after wich I would pass as a parameter to the command calling the executable, finnaly the text is converted back to a number(HANDLE) I tested it and it works for retrieving the handle

Comment: Does the elevated process need to a show console, or can you use `SW_HIDE` to hide it and have it call `FreeConsole` without worrying about attaching back to the elevated console?

Comment: Once the elevated process is detached via `FreeConsole`, reset its standard handles to `NULL` and call `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`. Then it can write to the parent's console using its standard output handle, or open "CONOUT$" and write to that instead.

Comment: I understand your intent, I'm just not sure what you'd expect `WriteConsoleA(argv[2],...)` to do when you've passed it a string and not a handle. You should certainly be getting a warning there. As @eryksun mentioned, it most likely will not work even if you do correct that, but it definitely won't if you don't.

Comment: Unrelated, but your attempt at converting an ANSI-encoded character string to a Unicode-encoded one does not in general work (it will for you, so long as you stick to ASCII characters, which a number does). In general, you should be using [std::to_wstring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are TWO ways that I know of to communicate with a child process directly.. One is to use pipes.. This allows you to write to the child process and also read from it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

PROCESS_INFORMATION CreateChildProcess(std::string CommandLine, std::string StartDirectory, DWORD WaitTime, HANDLE hInRead, HANDLE hOutWrite)
{
    STARTUPINFO SI;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI));
    ZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI));

    SI.cb = sizeof(SI);
    SI.hStdInput = hInRead;
    SI.hStdError = hOutWrite;
    SI.hStdOutput = hOutWrite;
    SI.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    bool success = CreateProcess(0, &CommandLine[0], 0, 0, true, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, StartDirectory.c_str(), &SI, &PI);

    if (success)
    {
        if (WaitTime != 0)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, WaitTime);
            CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
            return {0};
        }
        return PI;
    }

    return {0};
}


void RedirectInputPipe(HANDLE& hRead, HANDLE& hWrite)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attr;
    ZeroMemory(&attr, sizeof(attr));
    attr.nLength = sizeof(attr);
    attr.bInheritHandle = true;

    CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &attr, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(hWrite, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
}


void RedirectOutputPipe(HANDLE& hRead, HANDLE& hWrite)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attr;
    ZeroMemory(&attr, sizeof(attr));
    attr.nLength = sizeof(attr);
    attr.bInheritHandle = true;

    CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &attr, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(hRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
}

bool ReadPipe(HANDLE hOutput, std::string& Buffer)
{
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    Buffer.clear();
    Buffer.resize(256);
    bool Result = ReadFile(hOutput, &Buffer[0], Buffer.size(), &dwRead, NULL);
    Buffer.resize(dwRead);
    return Result && dwRead;
}

bool WritePipe(HANDLE hInput, const char* Buffer, unsigned int BufferSize)
{
    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    return WriteFile(hInput, Buffer, BufferSize, &dwWritten, NULL) && (dwWritten == BufferSize);
}

void HandleRead(HANDLE hOutputRead, bool &Termination)
{
    std::string Buffer;
    HANDLE ConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    while(!Termination)
    {
        if (!ReadPipe(hOutputRead, Buffer))
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)
                break;
        }

        WritePipe(ConsoleOutput, Buffer.c_str(), Buffer.size());
        if (output)
        {
            std::cout.write(Buffer.c_str(), Buffer.size());
        }
        Buffer.clear();
    }

    CloseHandle(ConsoleOutput);
}

int main()
{
    std::string process = "ChildProcess.exe";
    std::string startdir = "C:/Users/Brandon/Desktop/Test/bin";


    HANDLE hInputRead, hInputWrite, hOutputRead, hOutputWrite;
    RedirectInputPipe(hInputRead, hInputWrite);
    RedirectOutputPipe(hOutputRead, hOutputWrite);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI = CreateChildProcess(process, startdir, 0, hInputRead, hOutputWrite);

    bool Termination = false;
    std::thread(HandleRead, hOutputRead, std::ref(Termination)).detach();
    WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
    Termination = true;
    CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
    CloseHandle(hInputRead);
    CloseHandle(hInputWrite);
    CloseHandle(hOutputRead);
    CloseHandle(hOutputWrite);

    return 0;
}
```

It works by creating the child process with an input output handle to a pipe.. then create a thread that constantly polls/reads the pipe and prints out whatever it is writing.. cleanup when done..

The next way is to call `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)` according to the WinAPI docs.. This will attach the child process to the parent process' console. You need to call `FreeConsole` when done to detach from the parent process' console: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole

Comment: The first example isn't relevant to the OP as written. At best `ShellExecuteEx` supports only implicit standard-handle inheritance between parent and child console applications. On top of that, the OP is elevating via "runas", which marshals the request to the Application Information service, which calls `CreateProcessAsUser` without `bInheritHandles=FALSE` and with the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag. So there's no chance even for implicit inheritance. An alternative is to use named pipes and pass the name(s) in the command line.

Comment: That was supposed to be "calls `CreateProcessAsUser` *with* `bInheritHandles=FALSE`". I originally typed "without inheritance" and apparently fumbled the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I found a way to achieve what I wanted

I passed the parent PID to the child process by argument and then I used AttachConsole(PID)

voila!

Thank for the help of everyone

Comment: `ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS` should work. The Application Information service that creates the elevated process uses the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS` creation attribute 
  to set the requesting process as the parent (e.g. the process that calls `ShellExecuteEx` in this case).