# Writing in another process' console using API (without redirecting it's standard input)

Tags: c#, winapi, process

I'm looking for a way to write in another process' console using a WinApi, without redirecting the process' standard input.

Basically, my application (written in C#) is a wrap for another console application.

This third-party app accepts user commands in its console. My wrap application must start it and write such commands in it's console. Yet I'm restricted to redirect the standard input stream because it causes the thisrd-party application to crash.

So I'm looking for a solution using an WinAPI, (or other way) for solving this.

Here is a brief part of the code (hoping relevant for to depict what I'm trying to do):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = path
    ,Arguments = string.Join(" ", Args)
    ,UseShellExecute = false
    ,CreateNoWindow = true
    ,RedirectStandardOutput = true
    ,RedirectStandardError = true
    //,RedirectStandardInput = true //This leads the process to crash!
};

Process myProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo = startInfo
};

myProcess.Start();

/*...*/

public void SendInput(string input)
{
    //TODO: see how to send input to process' console   
    int result = SendMessage(myProcess.Handle, 0x000C, 0, input + '\n'); // Not working :(
}
```

Comment: "Yet I'm restricted to redirect the standard input stream because it causes the thisrd-party application to crash." Do you mean you can not use redirection because of a crash? That would make more sense. Yes, it is possible to remote a Console Application without being the one that started it. This is basic Desktop Automation.

Comment: I've seen this same question asked a few times recently. Do you have multiple accounts and keep asking it over and over?

Comment: Hello @Christopher, Yes, I cannot redirect because it causes the app to crash. And I don't know how, or have any idea, how can I send the input from my app to the third party console.

Comment: @Alex.C.: I already said, "Desktop Automation" is the droid you are looking for. I am only here because of the C# tag, so I can not give you a better answer.

Comment: Is this the sort of think you are looking for?  [How can I output text to another console already open C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46311795).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I found a solution by sending keystrokes to the process. E.g. If I want to write a full command, send the associated key code for each character form the command string, followed by an 'ENTER'.

Code:

```
    const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const uint KEY_ENTER = 13;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern short VkKeyScanA(char ch);

    public void SendInput(string input)
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, myProcess.MainWindowTitle);

        foreach(char c in input)
        {
            PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)VkKeyScanA(c)), IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)KEY_ENTER), IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```